# Android Webview Resize

Tags: android, webview

I have (again) a weird WebView problem.

Suppose it is loaded with this text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>T</title>
</head><body>noaeuvpraoisevuapnrsoievunapsoirevuanpsiorvunapeisovrnupaisovurapiosevraes<br></body></html>
```

When the WebView is resized from the screen rotation (in an activity that is not recreated on rotation), the text is made bigger.

This happens when the text does not fit to the screen and has to scroll right.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know what HTML Styles - CSS is?

Comment: There is no style. Just the html I pasted.